# Protractor test fails, but manually testing the same thing works (possibly related to $httpBackend)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, automation, jasmine, protractor

Alright, so my protractor test works if I'm not using a mock backend, and everything works as expected when I manually test the functionality (even with a mock backend). The only thing that doesn't work is the protractor test with $httpBackend.

I have the following test:

```
it("should navigate to add employee and add an employee.", function () {
    var tableRowsBeforeAdd = element.all(by.repeater("employee in ec.employees")).count();

    var button = element(by.className("btn"));
    button.click();

    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('add');

    var jmbgInput = element(by.model("ec.employee.jmbg"));
    jmbgInput.sendKeys("9988776655000");
    var nameInput = element(by.model("ec.employee.name"));
    nameInput.sendKeys("Test name");
    var surnameInput = element(by.model("ec.employee.surname"));
    surnameInput.sendKeys("Test surname");

    var submit = element(by.buttonText("Save"));
    submit.click();

    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).not.toContain('add');

    ...
```

Now, the browser opens (the default url points to a list view of employees), click on the correct button and opens the add/edit form for an employee. It enters the correct information into the input boxes, and it clicks on the button, but at that moment it crashes. The expect statement listed at the end of the code above, as well as all other expect blocks after that one fail, since it acts as if the list view didn't load, which it should, according to my service:

```
employee.$update().then(function() {
    employees.push(employee);
    $location.path('/');
});
```

My employee is a $resource service, and I'd avoid listing all the other code, as it's the same code that works when I use a real backend as well as when I manually use the app.

Now, one thing I'd like to add is the function which I run in the appe2e module:

```
function appe2ePrep($httpBackend, $location) {
    $httpBackend.whenGET("app/components/employee/employee-list.html").passThrough();
    $httpBackend.whenGET("app/components/employee/employee-detail.html").passThrough();
    var employees = [
        {jmbg:"1", name: "Mirko", surname: "Ivovkić"},
        {jmbg:"2", name: "Nikola", surname: "Tešić"},
        {jmbg:"3", name: "Robert", surname: "Stefanović"},
        {jmbg:"4", name: "Aleksa", surname: "Trifković"}
    ];
    // All employees
    $httpBackend.whenGET(dbEndpoint + "?apiKey=" + appKey).respond(employees);

    // adds a new employee
    $httpBackend.whenPUT(dbEndpoint + "/9988776655440?apiKey=" + appKey).respond(function (method, url, data) {
        return [200];
    });
}
```

From what I can tell there is a problem with the $location, or at least with the route as the page that should load after the click doesn't.

Comment: Do you have any error in console when running the test?

Comment: Only the ones related to expect statements not passing. For example, the error for the listed expect statement is: 'Expected http://localhost:8080/add not to contain add'.

Comment: In debug mode, when you enter `employee.$update()` does it executes ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm sorry for wasting everyone's time. I supplied the string "9988776655440" when I was expecting a "9988776655000". For some reason the debugger wasn't showing me a bad request, and all it took was to go over my SO post here to realize the strings don't match.